# MYSQL: How to search and replace data in one table a table with column from another table using a REGEXP

Tags: mysql, regex, database, foreach, string-parsing

Here's the basic idea of what I need to do.  I have two tables like the following:

```
Table A               Table B
|id|name       |     |id|sentence                                       |
|1 |hello      |     |1 |I like to say hello                            |
|2 |world      |     |2 |The world is large                             |
|3 |hello world|     |3 |lorem hello ipsum world lorem ipsum hello world|
```

I need to cycle through the rows in Table A to look for each name in Table B.  Then I want to use a REGEXP in Table B to replace the word if it is found.

For example if `hello` is found in Table B it will replace the word `hello` in Table B with `#~Hello~#` 
So the fist row in table B will turn into `I like to say #~Hello~#`

Thanks to [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)  for a great question. So I am updating the question.

Not only can rows in Table B contain multiple words from Table A, but Table A can also have rows that contain multiple word combinations. See row 3 in Table A for reference.

In this case the longest word combination should get replaced and the shorter combination/words should be skipped.  A proper working of the code would produce a Table B row 3 like the following:

```
lorem #~hello~# ipsum #~world~# lorem ipsum #~hello world~#
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I assume the sentences could contain multiple different words from `A`.  This makes the problem much harder, so you should include such an example.

Comment: See updates, thanks for the question.  You are right on with your assumptions.

Comment: That third condition is a doozy.  You should probably do this outside the SQL world.

Comment: So I have done this in PHP, but I am working with a Table A that is 1,000,000 rows and a Table B that is 70,000 rows, so the double embeded for each loop is way TOO SLOW, and by that I mean it will take close to a year to run.  I need a faster solution and MySQL is FAST.