# How to install MySQL UDF in WAMP Windows 10

Tags: mysql, wamp, udf

I am trying to install https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp/blob/master/README.md into WAMP on a Windows 10 64bit machine. I cannot figure it out for the life of me. Help please!

Comment: That extension looks a bit old and un-loved. Are you sure that is what you want to use?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I am trying to do a massive REGEXP find and replace on a large DB, and I cannot seem to figure out a better way to do it.  See my other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056127/mysql-for-each-loop-with-string-replacement-using-regexp?noredirect=1#comment53932964_33056127